# SQL Server: cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these two tables:

Storage:

```
id (int, PK) 
articleNr (nvarchar(10))
shelf (nvarchar(10))
number (int)
```

Orders:

```
orderNr (int, PK)
articleNr (nvarchar(10))
ordered (int)
picked (int)
```

I want to know how many items of a certain article number are available for purchase.

So the total number of articles is just

```
select sum(number) 
from storage 
group by articleNr
```

And the number of ordered and not yet picked articles is just

```
select sum(ordered) - sum(picked) 
from orders 
group by articleNr
```

So all I want to do really is to just subtract the latter from the former and I have my answer, but when I try to do that in a query I can't do that because it's a SUM within a SUM. What I really want to do is something like:

```
select sum(query1) - sum(query2)
```

(Where query1 is the first query above and query2 the second)

But when I do that I get the error message that's in the subject.

Comment: I don't get an error on any of the two queries that I have ther, but if I do this:

    select sum (query 1) - sum(query 2)

Then I get the error that's in the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
select coalesce(s.articleNr, o.articleNr) as articleNr, 
    coalesce(s.q_stored,0) - coalesce(o.q_topick,0) as q_remaining
from (
    select articleNr, sum(number) as q_stored
    from storage 
    group by articleNr) s
full join (
    select articleNr, sum(ordered) - sum(picked)  as q_topick
    from orders 
    group by articleNr
) o on o.articleNr = s.articleNr
```